# reformatting string to two string values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that converts a string that looks like `aaa-bbb|ccc-ddd|eee-fff` to two strings that look like `aaa|ccc|eee` and `bbb|ddd|fff`.

```
var id = "HEL-CAS|MAD-STO|XXX-YYY" 
var splittedId = id.split('|');
var from = "", to = "";
$(splittedId).each(function(a,b) {
    from = from + b.split("-")[0]+"|";
    to = to + b.split("-")[1] + "|";
});
from = from.substring(0,from.length-1);
to = to.substring(0,to.length-1);
```

The code works fine, but I am wondering if it's possible to do this in fewer operations / or with faster runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are few built-in array functions you may use to simplify your code. I don't think you will ever notice any performance difference but code will also be easier to read:

```
var id = "HEL-CAS|MAD-STO|XXX-YYY" 

// Format is fixed then it's easy to use a regex
var splittedId = id.split(/[\|-]/);

// Now we can pick "every other element" and then join strings
var from = splittedId.filter(function (v, i) {
    return i & 1 == 0;
}).join('|');

var to = splittedId.filter(function (v, i) {
    return i & 1 == 1;
}).join('|');
```